# Unity game doesn't work when I click "Maximize On Play" button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new on Unity.

As I mentioned before, My game doesn't work when I click "Maximize On Play" button ( in addition game doesn't switch to big screen). It works well on Window screen. Actually It was working before update. I updated Unity to 2019.4.12f1

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Any ideas ?????

Comment: Do you mean it's not playing or it's not maximized ? Are you pressing the button when the editor is already on play mode ? Did you try to right click on the game tab title and select `Maximize` ?

Comment: Bot of them. It's not maximized and it's not playing. Of course I'm not pressing the button when the editor is on play mode. As I said earlier It was working before updated Unity. @D.B

Comment: You press play button and nothing happend ? No error on console, no crash, nothing? The editor just don't play and the play button stay at normal state?

Comment: Yes. There is no crash, nothing happens. It really work well on Window Screen.
Btw Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Is there someone has any toughts???